# Aligning column headers(titles) with row items

Tags: list, css, column, list-item

I have a list in which the items are long string of characters. Due to this the Column titles are not perfectly aligned with item rows. The Column headers are not changing there original position and not getting aligned towards left as they normally do in normal list.

To give you a background i have freezed the header of a list using the below CSS:

```
 .ms-viewheadertr {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    }

 .ms-listviewtable tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 400px;
    }
```

So before adding CSS they look like this :

[image]

After adding CSS:

[image]

I am looking to do this through CSS/JavaScript/Jquery preferably by  Text wrap, increasing space between column or any other method.

Any help (SOLUTION/SUGGESTION/DISCUSSION/) is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Test with any proper words in department and description

Comment: I did same result.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot of "how the headers should be look like?"

Comment: Actually i have just used this list as  template .In real the list is pretty long so i have put it in a scroll pane ,freezing header row using  .ms-viewheadertr. After adding the CSS in CEWP all the headers are bunching towards left as seen in second screenshot.Ideally it should look like the first screenshot(Headers alignned with row from left) even after adding CSS.So it should look like the first screenshot above.Sorry if i misunderstood your question .i will add another one if you want.